# android Create ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am studying the Android development materials and now learning to add the ActionBar.

The following is the code of DisplayMessageActivity.java, which encountered the error  "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo":

```
package com.mycompany.myfa;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.*;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //from SF
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);

    //getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
           // openSearch();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            //openSettings();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

}
```

However, when I comment out the code "getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);"
The Apps can run successfully, but without any ActionBar. Do I miss anything so that "getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);" fails?

Thanks.

I have tried to use getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); but the error still insists. The following is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mycompany.myfa" >
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName=".MyActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.mycompany.myfa.MyActivity" />
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks again.

Comment: show your manifest file

Answer (score 0):

May be its theme problem, which you are using that does not support action bar..try to change your manifest file...

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
```

if its not working then try to do this

```
getSupportActionBar() or ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().
```

Hope it works..

Answer (score 0):

You are inheriting from `AppCompatActivity`. Hence, you need to use `getSupportActionBar()`, instead  `getActionBar()`, to get the appcompat-v7 supported action bar

also you need to add this xml tag in your `style.xml` theme.

```
<item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
```